# Calculate Phase angle between two signals

Tags: audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate Phase angle between two signals i.e. digital Phase meter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/calculate-phase-angle-between-two-signals-i-e-digital-phase-meter)

I want to calculate the phase difference between the two channels(signals) of a stereo audio file.(uncompressed data i.e. PCM samples).

I want to determine whether whether two signals are in phase or not i.e. kind of phase meter ?
Not the exact phase difference.

Can you please suggest a algorithm to calculate the phase difference.